# How to notify through email in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How to notify through email in wordpress when visitor clicks on a link that this link was pressed and/or user ip, city and country was this?
I have given the link a class 'email-link'.

Comment: Did my answer or one of the other help you? If so please mark the appropriate answer as the accepted solution. Or, post an update and we'll try to help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this as a direct consequence of WordPress since a link is HTML and has no correlation to or integration with anything controlled or processed directly by WordPress. WordPress is merely a structure/processes through which you can add info to a database and then later retrieve it.

If you question is actually meant in a more generic and not specifically wordPress sense, then the answer is any number of ways. You could for example create some JQuery or JS that would add that info everytime a link was clicked. But, you would need to interact with the page headers to try and get all the required info.

But, why bother doing that when a free & arguably market leading tool that does this is already available?

The logical process to this is to use Google Analytics (or a rival tool) as this already collects this kind of info with very little work required to set it up. If you want more specific "event" triggered data (eg a link is clicked), then you can also do this fairly easily too.

https://analytics.google.com

***UPDATE***

In your comment, you clarify that you want a real time email to be sent to you when a link is clicked, and thus analytics isn't going to fit the bill. In that case you will need to do some work using JQuery & AJAX.

In simple terms you'll need to do something this:

1) Create some JQuery to intercept the url of the link clicked

2) Pass the link (and header info) to a function via an AJAX call

3) Process the header data / send the email

4) Redirect user to the url passed from the link

Here's a tutorial on creating a simple AJAX process in WordPress: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/tutorial-ajax-wordpress/

Comment: I want to be notified by email when the user clicks on a particular link on my website. I know analytics can tell me in dept but it cannot send me such notification.

Comment: @MarkAnderson This is not a feature that can be done directly via WordPress. It simply doesn't know when a link is clicked. You would need to do som work with JQuery or JS in that case. I've added a little extra info in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should get you started

```
// functions.php
// HTML form markup
function mail_form_stuff() {
    echo '<form action="' . esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) . '" method="post">';
    echo '<p><input type="submit" name="send_the_email_to_admin" value="Click this button"></p>';
    echo '</form>';
}

// make sure the email will allow for html -- not just plain text
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'send_the_email_to_admin_content_type' );
function send_the_email_to_admin_content_type() {
  return 'text/html';
}

// if the button is clicked, send the email
function deliver_mail_link_stuff() {
  $admin_email = get_option( 'admin_email' );
  if ( isset($_POST["send_the_email_to_admin"]) ) {
    $_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $_name = esc_html( $_user->user_firstname );
    $_email = esc_html( $_user->user_email );

    $to = $admin_email;
    $subject = "Some person clicked my link";
    $message = 'Hey this person clicked on that button'.'<br>';
    $message .= "the persons email address was: $_email";

    $headers[] = "From: $_name <$_email>" . "\r\n";
    // $headers[] = "Bcc: John Smith <jsmith@gmail.com>" . "\r\n";

    // If everything worked -- display a success message
    if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ) ) {
        echo '<p>sent</p>';
    } else {
        echo 'An unexpected error occurred';
    }
    // reset wp_mail_content_type
    remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'send_the_email_to_admin_content_type' );
    }
}

function add_short_code_stuff() {
    ob_start();
    deliver_mail_link_stuff();
    mail_form_stuff();
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'EMAIL_BUTTON', 'add_short_code_stuff' );
```

this will add a short code for you

you can then call the shortcode in your theme with

```
echo do_shortcode('[EMAIL_BUTTON]');
```

Comment: But what if I have more than such buttons? I want to give a class name 'email-link' to one link so that it can generate email and notify me that the visitor click on link 'A'. For link 'B' class can be 'email-link-b'. Any solution?

Comment: Also, this doesn't deal with sending the visitor onto the required uri ...